# Keras Custom Objective requires Tensor Evaluation

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I want to create a custom objective function for training a Keras deep net. I'm researching classification of imbalanced data, and I use the F1 score a lot in scikit-learn. I therefore had the idea of inverting the F1 metric (1 - F1 score) to use it as a loss function/objective for Keras to minimise while training:

```
(from sklearn.metric import f1_score)

def F1Loss(y_true, y_pred):

    return 1. - f1_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

However, this `f1_score` method from scikit-learn requires numpy arrays or lists to calculate the F1 score. I found that Tensors need to be evaluated to their numpy array counterparts using `.eval()`, which requires a TensorFlow session to perform this task.

I do not know the session object that Keras uses. I have tried using the code below, assuming the Keras backend has its own session object defined somewhere, but this also did not work.

```
from keras import backend as K

K.eval(y_true)
```

Admittedly, this was a shot in the dark since I don't really understand the deeper workings of Keras or Tensorflow a the moment.

**My question is: how do I evaluate the `y_true` and `y_pred` tensors to their numpy array counterparts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a classic problem with implementing a discontinous objective in Theano. It's impossible beacuse of two reasons:

1. **F1-score is discontinous :** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236856/how-does-the-back-propagation-algorithm-deal-with-non-differentiable-activation/37011728#37011728) you can read what should be expected from an objective function in neural networks training. F1-score doesn's satisfy this conditions - so it cannot be used to train neural network.
2. **There is no equivalency between Tensor and Numpy array:** it's an fundamental issue. Theano tensor is like ***x*** in school equations. You cannot expect from an algebraic variable to be equivalent any object to which it can be assigned to. On the other hand - as a part of a computational graph - a tensor operations should be provided in order to compute objective. If not - you cannot differentiate it w.r.t. parameters what makes most of usual way of training of a neural network impossible.

Comment: This was very helpful! I would not have thought of these points myself. Thank you. I will look for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have predicted and actual tensors in numpy array format then I guess that you can use this code snippet:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(actual_tensor,1), tf.argmax(predicted_tensor,1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

And in keras, I think that you can use this:

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, nb_val_samples=X_val.shape[0],
                        samples_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0], nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1,
                        callbacks=[model_checkpoint, reduce_lr, tb], max_q_size=1000)
```

Where train_generator and val_generator generates the training and validation data while training and this also prints the loss and accuracies while training.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer, but I don't have them in numpy array format. I am actually looking for a way to convert the tensors `y_true` and `y_pred` to numpy arrays. I want them in numpy array format so I can feed them into the F1 function, which simply returns a scalar number.

Comment: Objects return by .eval() method are in numpy array, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I clearly stated I tried this already in the description of my question. It doesn't work without a session object though and I don't know what session object Keras uses by default. However, as stated by the answer above, using the F1 metric is not a mathematically valid approach anyways, so I'm going to try a different method.